# Rest API, redirecting to payment gateway

Tags: php, rest, paypal

Im developing a REST API resource in which payment is required.The request contains the following

POST :

```
{
    "mobileNo" : "9999999999",
    "amount" : "10",
    "email":"testign@test.com"
}
```

Once the request is made , I want the user to get redirected to a payment gateway. How will I handle this API call?  Should I give a redirection status  (3**) and do a hidden form POST in the API to the payment gateway? or expose the whole resource as a GET?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple javascript. Take a look at this code. Hope it helps.

```
<form name="ecom" method="post" action="<!--your--paymentgatewayURL-->" id="pay_form"><input type="hidden" name="requestparameter" value="<!--your parameters-->"></form><script>document.getElementById('pay_form').submit();</script>
```